# Cocos 2dx 2.2.6 - getting random crash from CCEGLView::swapBuffers

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am using Cocos 2dx 2.2.6 . Sometimes the app crashes from

```
  [[EAGLView sharedEGLView] swapBuffers];
```

I use  iPhone 4 , os version - 6.1.3. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I added zorder value  -1  in      addChild()     .Seems fixed my issue.